# How to restrict directly invoking super type class's method and only can access through subtype class methode using subtype instance in java?

Tags: java

I am writing an algorithm that extends the ArrayList class.Here,using algorithm class's instance ,can invoke ArrayList's all the method.How can i restrict that only can invoke methode which is defined in algorithm class and Algorithm class can only access all ArrayList's method through its own method??
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't extend the `ArrayList`. Instead instantiate it as a private member field. With that you have full control over the list. e.g.

```
public class YourList<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> list;

    public YourList() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    // example method
    public void add(T t) {
        list.add(t);
    }

}
```

I added a type parameter `T` since you do not want to use raw types. You would use it like this

```
YourList<String> list = new YourList<>();
list.add("String");
YourList<Integer> otherList = new YourList<>();
list.add(1);
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to "force" your users to call your subclass.

By design, Java will run methods overridden in the subclass only, given an instance of a subclass of `ArrayList`. The superclass, `ArrayList`, will provide the API (you can't prevent other classes from having access to public methods declared in the superclass), but all overridden methods will run as defined in your subclass.

Your subclass may then choose to run the method implementation in `ArrayList` by using the `super` keyword when appropriate.